# Return a value and a result set from stored procedure classic asp

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I want to get both a return code and a result set back from a stored procedure in classic ASP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEmployeeId
@EmployeeName nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE 
      @Exists       INT 
    , @RowCount     Int = 0
    , @ReturnValue  Int = 1


SELECT EmployeeId FROM Employees WHERE Name = @EmployeeName
set @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

if (@RowCount <> 1)
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnValue = 2 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnValue = 1
END

RETURN @ReturnValue 
END
```

So in ASP I can do the following to get the return value

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnnstr
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "CheckEmployeeId"
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters("@EmployeeName")    = EmployeeName
end with
cmd.Execute()
RetVal = cmd.Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE")
```

or this to get the result set.

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnnstr
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "CheckEmployeeId"
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters("@EmployeeName")    = EmployeeName
    Set rst = .Execute()
end with
```

Is there a way to get both?

Comment: The return value is intended to return a status code of the execution, not to return values. If you want to receive values back from a procedure you should use OUTPUT parameters.

Comment: @SeanLange they're using it to return the status of the execution, 2 for no records and 1 for some.

Comment: @Lankymart I will politely disagree. That is not returning a status of the execution, it is returning a logical value. This is a great example of when we should use an output parameter.

Comment: @SeanLange honestly you're splitting hairs, you want to be pedantic about it that's up to you. Even Microsoft don't agree - see [RETURN (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174998.aspx) - Example B. Returning status codes.

Comment: @Lankymart probably correct. I tend to prefer using a output parameter instead. :)

Comment: @SeanLange a lot of it is personal preference to be honest, I wasn't disagreeing with you just think *"not to return values"* is less an opinion and more a command. I'd probably use `OUTPUT` it this instance to be honest but each to their own.

Comment: @Lankymart I certainly didn't take it any other way. As you said it is mostly preference.

Answer (score 6):

You are already doing it just combine the two.

```vb
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnnstr
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "CheckEmployeeId"
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters("@EmployeeName") = EmployeeName
    Set rst = .Execute()
end with
'You will need to close the Recordset before returning the RETURN_VALUE.
RetVal = cmd.Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE")
```

You don't need to choose one or the other the are independent of each other. The only issue will be the order they return, remember that both `OUTPUT` and `RETURN` values will not be accessible until all returned Recordsets are closed.

Personally, I prefer to close them straight away by storing them as 2 Dimensional Arrays.

```vb
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnnstr
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "CheckEmployeeId"
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters("@EmployeeName") = EmployeeName
    Set rst = .Execute()
    If Not rst.EOF Then data = rst.GetRows()
    Call rst.Close()
end with
RetVal = cmd.Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE")

'Access Recordset array
If IsArray(data) Then
  'Return first column, first row.
  Response.Write data(0, 0)
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I always get a vartype of 0 (vbEmpty - Indicates Empty (uninitialized))

Comment: @DavidElliott that's because the `Recordset` object has to be closed before you can read any `OUTPUT` or `RETURN` values. See [Value Property (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/value-property-ado) specifically the Note box - *"If a command contains a Parameter whose Value property is empty, and you create a Recordset from the command, ensure that you first close the Recordset before retrieving the Value property."*