# ASP Classic vbScript - Execute SQL stored procedure with recordset and returned values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with input parameters, a recordset returned and a return parameter.  When I go to the asp page, I get a 500 error.  The stored procedure runs as expected in SQL Server by itself.  Can you tell where the errors are in the below code?

```
    ' The following line must be changed to reflect your data source info
   Conn.Open "Data Source=path; Initial Catalog=database;","username","password"
   set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
  ' Specify the name of the stored procedure you wish to call
    cmd.CommandText = "ap_RF_085"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

  ' Use the values from the table in the following lines to define parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Whse_Loc", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Whse_Zone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Width_Char", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Height_Char", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Depth_Char", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Site", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8)
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Loc") = "4H"
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Zone") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Width_Char") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Height_Char") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Depth_Char") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Type") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Site") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Loc") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Loc") = "MZ"
    SET rs = cmd.Execute
    returned = cmd.parameters("@RETURN_VALUE").value

    RESPONSE.WRITE(returned)
```

Thanks for your help!

I updated my code to the suggestion below.  I am still getting a 500 error.  Also the tab in IE11 show "Waiting on [serverName]".  Can you tell why from the code what is not being passed correctly?

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Whse_Loc", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Whse_Zone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Width_Char", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Height_Char", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Depth_Char", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Type", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Site", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8)
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Loc") = "4H"
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Zone") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Width_Char") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Height_Char") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Depth_Char") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Type") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Site") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Loc") = ""
    cmd.Parameters("@Whse_Loc") = "MZ"
    SET rs = cmd.Execute
    IF NOT rs.EOF THEN data = rs.GETROWS()
    CALL rs.CLOSE()
    returned = cmd.parameters("@RETURN_VALUE").value
```

Comment: You can't access the return parameter before closing your recordset. Simplest way is to use `GetRows()` to store the recordset into a 2 dimensional array then close the recordset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a value and a result set from stored procedure classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069955/return-a-value-and-a-result-set-from-stored-procedure-classic-asp)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That other page has good info.  What I am also running into is that when I run the page I get "Waiting for [serverName]" in the tab of ie11.  Can you see anything in the code that could be causing issues?

Comment: You are very welcome, hope it's helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this: **Procedure**

```
DECLARE @RETURN_VALUE XXXXXX = NULL 
OUTPUT ASP file SET cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.command") 
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn cmd.CommandText = "" cmd.CommandType = 4 cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000 cmd.Parameters.refresh 
cmd.Execute returned = cmd.Parameters.item("@RETURN_VALUE") 
& "" RESPONSE.WRITE(returned) 
cmd.close 
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Hello, @220! You may want to consider formatting your answer, and including the code in a block. You can do this by indenting it properly and inserting newlines, and then  selecting the code and pressing control-K on your keyboard. This puts the code in a block of its own while preserving formatting.

Otherwise, you may find the code isn't really intelligible to readers and your answer may not be accepted, even though it may be a good one. Cheers!